# WELD-000044 Unable to obtain instance from org.jboss.weld.bean-se-module-ProducerField

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, cdi, entitymanager, weld

I am trying to inject an entity manager in a DAO class and test it, using weld container, but i keep getting the following exception:

org.jboss.weld.exceptions.NullInstanceException: WELD-000044 Unable to obtain instance from org.jboss.weld.bean-se-module-ProducerField-com.playground.cdi_tutorial.beans.Resources.em
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.CallableMethodHandler.invoke(CallableMethodHandler.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.CleanableMethodHandler.invoke(CleanableMethodHandler.java:43)
    at javax.persistence.EntityManager_$$_javassist_2.createQuery(EntityManager_$$_javassist_2.java)
    at com.playground.cdi_tutorial.model.EventDAO.getAllEvents(EventDAO.java:22)
    at com.playground.cdi_tutorial.beans.ValidationService.validateEvenNumbers(ValidationService.java:23)
    at com.playground.cdi_tutorial.beans.MyFactory.sayHi(MyFactory.java:15)
    at com.playground.cdi_tutorial.beans.MyFactoryTest.should_say_bye(MyFactoryTest.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

I try to inject the entity manager as follows:

```
 @Inject
 @EmProducer
 EntityManager em;
```

where EmProducer looks like this:

```
@Qualifier
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface EmProducer {

    public static final String UNIT_NAME = "cdi-tutorial";
```

}

And the producer class looks like this:

```
public class Resources {

 @Produces
 @EmProducer
 @PersistenceContext(unitName = EmProducer.UNIT_NAME)
 private EntityManager em;
       ...
    }
```

In my test, when this line of code is hit Query q = em.createQuery("from Employee"); I get the exception above. The entity manager, em, is not null though.

PS: I use WeldJUnit4Runner (http://www.hostettler.net/blog/2012/04/02/how-to-test-a-jsf-named-bean/) to run my tests.

I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [Arquillian](http://www.jboss.org/arquillian.html) for this kind of test. It makes in-container tests really easy (and fast). You can just inject EntityManager normally and Arquillian takes care of the rest...

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly what I want to avoid. I don't need all the services offered by an application server, I just need to be able to inject managed beans, including the entity manager itself. I think the problem is related to the fact that @PersistenceContext annotation is not 'recognized' by Weld Container. I'll try using another Producer, by creating the EntityManager with the help of EntityManagerFactory.

Comment: OK, but just give it a try for Arquillian when you have time. Tests run really fast, you can deploy to a running server(remote) or start and stop the server in the test(managed). There is a tutorial for testing persistence at: http://arquillian.org/guides/testing_java_persistence/ About starting all services, if you are using Glassfish or JBoss, they start really fast because the don't load unused services.